# How can I query a ip in mysql a custom range content?

Tags: mysql, sql

In my MySQL table `client_ip_dada`, there is a field named `ip_content`, in it

the content is like this:

`ServerIPs: 1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2, 3.3.3.3/4.4.4.4-10`
`ServerIPs: 103.11.7.8-20`
`ServerIPs: 8.1.3.2-10`
`ServerIPs: 123.1.45.9`

now I will write a API to query out a client_ip_dada list by passing a ip list `[103.11.7.8, 8.1.3.4, 123.1.45.7]`.

there will query out

```
[
    ServerIPs: 103.11.7.8-20,
    ServerIPs: 8.1.3.2-10
    null,
]
```

but in MySQL there is no range query like this. so is there possible to do with this?

Answer (score 0):

Spilt it into two columns:

Like for 103.11.7.8-20

Make one column for maximum range 103.11.7.20
Make one column for minimum range 103.11.7.8

Later query it with >= and =< with both columns.

Comment: Can you tell me how? Please give a detail example.